# ACF Image size output from taxonomy

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created an ACF field for images in taxonomy = post category. I have written a loop which outputs these images and works. I have added this at the bottom of the post as a reference.

Now I want to choose the image size and so I have tried the more advanced method which uses wp_get_attachment_image (outlined here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/) :

```
$attachment_id = get_field('field_name');
$size = "full"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size) 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
```

So I changed the above to

```
$attachment_id = get_field('category_image', $taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
$size = "full"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size) 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
```

and in image added

```
echo $image[0]
```

But this outputs bool(false) and does not work. Any ideas?

**Here is the code which outputs the image url correctly in a loop.**

```
<div class="category-image">
    <?php


    $taxonomy = 'category';
    $queried_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var($taxonomy), 0 );
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);


    if ($terms) {
      echo '<ul>';
      foreach($terms as $term) {

// ACF

$image = get_field('category_image', $taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);     

// TEST to see field    
// var_dump( $image );


if( get_field('category_image', $taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id)):


?> <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ; ?>" alt="" /><h4><?php echo $term->name ?></h4></a></li>

<?php  endif; } ?>
</ul> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the image field returning an object (this is good), which would mean you could solve this really easily by pulling the Url for the size you want directly from the returned Image object like so:

> `<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large'] ; ?>" alt="" />`

The object returned by `get_field('category_image')` looks like this:

```
Array(
[id] => 540
[alt] => A Movie
[title] => Movie Poster: UP
[caption] => sweet image
[description] => a man and a baloon
[url] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
[sizes] => Array
    (
        [thumbnail] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up-150x150.jpg
        [medium] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up-300x119.jpg
        [large] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
        [post-thumbnail] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
        [large-feature] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
        [small-feature] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up-500x199.jpg
    ));
```

Soruce: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/#template-usage